# Color Correction in DirectX

Tags: directx, directx11, color

After playing games like Star Wars Battlefront & GTA 5 I was wondering how dev's implement Color Correction in their Engines. I know that this can be done through the use of 3D LUT's but I was wondering if there are any other ways to do this. A good example of this would be in GTA 5 when a Characters special ability is triggered the colors on screen have a tint applied to them which over a period of 2 seconds the intensity of the effect gradually increases.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LNGF7J3y5_Y

If someone can explain how this is done/ implemented that would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Color correction is commonly done through post processing shaders. Basically first you render the scene to a framebuffer, then draw a fullscreen quad that has a shader that takes that framebuffer and applies some effects on it. This is how color correction, bloom, dof, motionblur etc. are done these days.

Here is a simple GLSL shader performing gamma correction.

```
uniform sampler2D framebuffer;
uniform vec2 resolution;

void main()
{
    //Read the framebuffer
    vec4 inColor = texture2D(framebuffer, gl_FragCoord.xy / resolution);
    float gamma = 2.2;
    //Gamma correct
    gl_FragColor = vec4(pow(inColor.rgb, vec3(1.0/gamma)), 1);
}
```